# Calling a function using only kwargs when args, kwargs is expected

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

I am writing a wrapper around TA-lib to invoke the functions as part of a pipeline. Some of the function have expected and optional parameters. I expected to simply use warts and map the named parameters, but **it only seems to be mapping the expected parameters and is not mapping the optional parameters.**

```
import pandas as pd
from talib import abstract

class TALibAugments():
    """
    Augment with TA-lib functions
    Parameter documentation: https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/
    Function Sample: real = MA(close, timeperiod=30, matype=0)
    """
    def __init__(self, function_name, out_cols, **kwargs):
        self.ta_lib_function = abstract.Function(function_name)
        self.out_cols = out_cols
        self.ta_lib_kwargs = kwargs

    def augment(self, df, concat=False):
        fn_result = self.ta_lib_function(self.ta_lib_kwargs) # Problem here

        df_out = None
        if len(self.out_cols) == 1:
            df_out = pd.DataFrame(fn_result, index=df.index, columns=self.out_cols)
        else:
            df_out = pd.DataFrame()
            for i in range(0, len(fn_result)):
                df_out[self.out_cols[i]] = pd.Series(fn_result[i], index=df.index)
        
        return df_out
```

Instantiated thusly

```
ma_slow_augments = TALibAugments("MA", ["ma_slow"], close=df_resampled["close"], timeperiod=100, matype=0)
```

I am not sure what _Function does
This is the code from the TA-lib abstract.Function function:

```
def Function(function_name, *args, **kwargs):
    func_name = function_name.upper()
    if func_name not in _func_obj_mapping:
        raise Exception('%s not supported by TA-LIB.' % func_name)

    return _Function(
        func_name, _func_obj_mapping[func_name], *args, **kwargs
    )
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `self.ta_lib_function(**self.ta_lib_kwargs)`?

Comment: I did try that: TypeError: Argument 'high' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got NoneType), called when defines as atr_augment = TALibAugments("ATR", ["atr"], high=df_resampled["high"], low=df_resampled["low"], close=df_resampled["close"]).  TA-LIB signature: real = ATR(high, low, close, timeperiod=14)

Comment: Well, that seems to indicate that `high`, `low` and `close` aren't keyword arguments, so you should try using `*args` for those.